# postgres log workflow : filter the log events with specific working hours

Tags: postgresql, syslog, rsyslog

To analyze postgres logs, our workflow is:

1. postgres logs via syslog
2. rsyslog writes to one text file
3. at midnight we stop postgres
4. pgbadger reads and parses the daily logfile (about 2 Gbyte)

We want to esclude some outliers, for examples when the application starts, because for us they are useless data and just pollute the logfile.

To accomplish this: how/where can I specify a working hours (from..to) filter ?

The ideal solution is to set the filter in postgres.

Less than ideal, filter at rsyslog.

Last choice is to filter at pgbadger: the html output will be trimmed, but our servers keep writing fat logfiles.

---

current rsyslog configuration:

```
:msg, contains, "connection authorized: user=root database=root" ~
:msg, contains, "FATAL:  database \"root\" does not exist" ~
local0.*    -/var/log/postgresql.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a filter using the time in `rsyslog.conf` using the *system properties* holding the current time, like `hour` and `minute`. For example,

```
if $$hour >= '10' and $$hour <='17' then /var/log/output
```

As I understand it, the hour and minute values are 2 character strings with leading zero.

You can combine this with a test for the facility (local0 and so on), for example:

```
if ( $syslogfacility-text=='local0' ) and ( $$hour <= '10' or $$hour>='20' ) then stop
```

(where `stop` is the newer way of saying `~`), or if you prefer

```
if ( $syslogfacility-text=='local0' ) and ( $$hour > '10' and $$hour<'20' ) then /var/log/output
```

Note that these filters must be on one line starting in the first column.

Comment: pls see my update

Comment: I don't grok howto match your suggestion with our configuration (excerpt above)

Comment: I updated my answer to show the sort of expressions you can use.

Comment: Legacy intranet servers, running centos 5 and 6. I upgrade from rsyslog v5 to v6. thanks